# insert id value with @ in them

Tags: jquery, html

I have my data-id as such:

```
    data-id="@r@Model.Param
```

Note that @r and @Model.Param are dynamic values. How do I put "value" between the 2. As such, I like it to be

```
   data-id="@rvalue@Model.Param
```

if @r is 5 adn @Model.Param is 44 then it will show as data-id="544"

The thing is I need to capture the value of @Model.Param so what I am trying to do is to delimit it.

I want it to show as 5value44

but it does not work as it treats it as @rvalue which has no value.

Comment: Not 100% clear what you're asking. Could you make a quick working example?

Comment: In what way are these "dynamic"?  Are you using some other technology not mentioned here?

Comment: Why not just use two different data attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[assuming you're using Razor in ASP.NET MVC, based on the `@Model` syntax...]

Combine them in the server-side code.  Something like this:

```
data-id="@($"{r}value{Model.Param}")"
```

Or, if this syntax is unavailable:

```
data-id="@(string.Format("{0}value{1}", r, Model.Param))"
```